# Chrome nacl error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I tried to install chrome in my ubuntu 14.04 64amd with :

```
 apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

but when I run

```
google-chrome
```

I get this error :

> ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(316)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0
> bytes)

**EDIT** :

Just a hint, I'm using SSH to connect to the server.

And I'm running a non root User.

What should I do ?

Comment: It appears that you might be running as root (if you weren't, you would have to run `sudo apt-get...`). Trying to run Chrome as root is not a good idea, and is the cause of your issue. As a test, please run `google-chrome` as a *non-root user* and report back the results.

Resource: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175967/60677

Comment: I created a normal user with adduser and the problem persists

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid, but did you log in as that user ? If you are on the command line / in a terminal - type `id` to see which user (and user id) you currently are.  If you want to change to your new user, you can do that with `su - <username>` or `sudo su - <username>`

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure, I'm on a user called desktop and not root

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: you need to enable X11 forwarding on your server, where you connect to with ssh:  add `X11Forwarding yes`into your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart the ssh service `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` then connect to it with a new (!) ssh session`ssh -X username@host` and try to open chrome again

Comment: Add your response and i'll accept it

Comment: Done ! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using chrome on a remote server, via SSH, you need to **enable X11 forwarding on your server**, where you connect to with ssh.

Add `X11Forwarding yes` into your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server, with an editor

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and restart the ssh service

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

then connect to it with a new (!) ssh session

```
ssh -X username@my-chrome-host
```

and try to open chrome again.

If you don't want to enter `-X`every time you connec to this host, you can also modify your client config

nano .ssh/config

add a portion for your host

```
Host my-chrome-host
ForwardX11 yes
```

or to have it always enabled you can use wild-cards

```
Host *
ForwardX11 yes
```